# The exact value of an irrational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As we know we can not get an exact value of the irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$ but as we know also we can represent the irrational number on the number so we can measure the length of the line segment whose length is $\sqrt{2}$  , this means that we got an exact value of it 
So what is the problem with this ?

Comment: No measurement is exact.

Comment: How do you define "exact value"?  It appears first it is a finite decimal, but later it is a geometric construction.  Different numbers can be represented by the two techniques, so it is not surprising that some, like $\sqrt 2$ can be represented by one and not the other.  There is no problem.  How about $\frac 13?$.  Its decimal does not terminate, so maybe that would say we cannot know its exact value, but the fraction seems acceptable.  Similarly, I find $\sqrt 2$ a fine representation of an exact value.

Comment: "As we know we can not get an exact value of the irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$" What exactly (hehehe) does that mean? What makes one method of representing numbers (e.g. by finite decimal expansions, or by fractions) "more exact" than another (e.g. by an algebraic equation)?

Comment: The continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt 2$ repeats. So we have that exact value just as surely as we have the value of $0.3333...$ which also repeats.

Comment: "If you discourse with me you must define your terms"--- Voltaire.... What is your $definition$ of "exact value"?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That quote is so delightfully pompous.

Comment: yes, we can draw (construct) the line of length $\sqrt{2}$ exactly, but we can measure it up to any (certain) precision limited by the measuring instrument.

Comment: @N.Bar .  In a televised interview of President Clinton during the Monica Lewinzky scandal, he repeatedly replied to Q's with " Well, that depends on what your definition of ....... is.".  Finally he actually said "Well, that depends on what your definition of IS is."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that an exact value is a number, $n$ which is equal to, not an approximation of, an irrational number (Example: $n=\sqrt{2}$). Obviously, this isn't a very rigorous definition, but it gets the point across.

Let's take your example of a line segment which is perfectly equal to the $\sqrt{2}$. The hypotenuse of a 45-45-90 triangle is equal to $\sqrt{2}$ when the legs are each equal to 1, so just visualize that in your mind. Okay, we have our segment, now all we have to do is measure it...right? Well, it's not that easy. Every single measurement is within a certain degree of accuracy -- it can't be perfect. We might get a very good approximation of an irrational number, such as 1.4, but we won't get the exact value. Now, even if we had some impossible ruler that could perfectly measure any line segment, $\sqrt{2}$ (and all irrational numbers) are non-terminating and non-repeating, meaning that we would need an infinitely long screen to display all of the digits (and an infinitely long amount of time if the numbers appear sequentially on our hypothetical ruler). Therefore, it is impossible to get the exact value of a rational number even if we have an impossibly perfect measuring tool.

Comment: That is the same my opinion like the situation of the irrational number $\pi$ One says that as $\pi$ is the ratio between the circumference of the circle and its diameter length so we can get its exact value by drawing a circle of some radius length and measure its circumference then do the division , but i said every time you draw the circle you will get different value little bit @N. Bar